# JQuery Stopping a button from being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I am trying to build kind of a Minesweeper game and I require some help regarding the end game. I made the table for the game to be a function generated table using JQuery. What I need is for when the game finishes, to not allow the user to click on any of the cells in the table. So far this is what I tried:

```
if(gameField[rand][col]==1){
    $(button).text("X");
    checkForBombs();
    var endGame = confirm("You lost. Do you want to play again?");
        if(endGame === true){
            window.location.reload();
        }
        if(endGame === false){
            $('#tableboard').click(function(event){
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
}
```

It essentially checks if the endGame is reached and then, based on user input it starts a new game or not. When the user presses cancel, the table should not take any inputs from the user anymore.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved will be greatly appreciated. I do not need the exact code, however guidance or a proper function that makes buttons inactive while still displaying the information at the endGame would be appreciated.

Comment: What about `$(button).attr('disabled', 'disabled');` if `endGame === false` and add `event.preventDefault();` in your `#tableboard` click handler?

Comment: Thank you. That made it work.

Comment: Great, please consider accepting [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31670866/2788131) if it solved your problem then.

Comment: The answer you posted is useful but it cannot be applied in this case due to other functions that I have in my code. I posed my answer with credits to you for the idea. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply disable the button:

```
$('.your-button').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This only disabled the button that had the bomb on it, not everything in the table. I will keep this in mind though for future mini-projects that I will make.

Comment: Gotcha. I guess I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you've bound an event earlier to the element `$('#tableboard')` to accept click events. If that's true just unbind any click event bound to that element in your endgame code.

```
if(endGame === false){
    $('#tableboard').unbind('click');
}
```

Comment: I did not add a click event in the HTML. I have a function called onclick and that takes care of the button creation.

Comment: Could you post the function so we can take a look!

Comment: Yes. Here is the link for the function: http://jsbin.com/dadinoxeni/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
if(endGame === false) {
    $('#tableboard').attr('disabled', 'disabled').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that made it work:

```
if(endGame === false){
            $('#tableboard button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                event.preventDefault()

        }
```

Thank you D4V1D for the idea. 
Essentially, if the user cancels a new game, every button in the table is disabled and he can review the game and where the bombs are at.